# Brown sediment in shower, nothing works

Tags: cleaning

I have an ensuite shower with white floor (or call it pad) which is from some kind of composite plastic material.
Over time, brown discoloration and sediments started to acumulate in areas where the foam from shower session is not able to dissipate immediately, and stic kthre for extended time periods.
This, contrary to calcium sediments on the glass door, which can be easily cleaned by applying cytric acid solution, is resisting all my efforts to remove.
I tried mechanical removal (to the extent possible to not damage the white material), bleach, citric acid, baking soda, all the £5 cleaning solution from my local supermarket and DIY shops. Nothing works.

Can you please tell me what it is and recommend a chemical solution that is safe to humans, but can dissolve this thing?

See two photos of the issue here ->
https://postimg.cc/gallery/xCFzw2G

Answer (score 3):

These brown deposits are probably containing iron(III) hydroxides, oxides  or carbonates. They should be easily eliminated by concentrated $\ce{HCl}$, but this acid may also attack the floor. You might try using wet Rochelle salt, which is the common name for potassium sodium tartrate. Action of this compound should clean the spot, but not immediately. Try !